# Excel help - extract all unique values from column a in multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a sheet called output, and a sheet for each month a jan, feb etc.

Without vba, is there a formula I can use to extract all information from column A in the month sheets, into column a in the output sheet but keeping only the unique values?

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Comment: Ive had plenty of people on here make suggestions that have helped me create or amend formulas. 

I’m not after “code”, I’m asking if there’s a formula that I can do it with, WITHOUT vba. It may not be possible. 

Thanks anyway

Comment: Why not use pivot tables? If you then choose to you could have just one output sheet (with a month filter) instead of a separate sheet for every month...

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to look into the `UNIQUE()` function.

One call for each Month (array), and maybe have those inside another call to `UNIQUE` - I have not tried that though.

Ref:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e

Comment: Thank you, but I’m looking for a solution without code

Comment: Ahh... missed that "withOUT".

Comment: No worries, cool of you for taking the time anyway - Ty

Comment: Update, totally changed.

Comment: Thank you - annoyingly excel 2016 doesn’t have the unique function

Comment: What kind of information do you have in these monthly worksheets, and what do you want the result to look like? Show us an example.

Comment: Hi , I’ll knock up an example but basically in the month sheets I paste a monthly ebitda. 

In each mint sheet, in column a a3:a20000, there’s a list such as 5000 food revenue, 4000 first aid costs. Then on the right are the costs. 

In the output sheet a3:a20000,  I want to extract all of the columns a3:a20000. That will give me a list of all the unique costs and revenue types. I’ll then use a v look up formula to pull the figures for each month. This gives me a yearly overview